# Calling `stepDown` or `stepUp` doesn't trigger `change` or `input` event on range input

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, event-handling

When calling `stepDown` and `stepUp` on a `<input type='range'>`, the `input` or `change` events are not being triggered.

[Here's a code sample of the issue in action:](https://codepen.io/rickyabrooks92/pen/wvXNgxz)

```html
<p>J and K move slider left and right but aren't triggering event. 
Using mouse though successfully updates label.</p>

<p>Label isn't updating on keypress which is 
calling <code>stepDown()</code> and <code>stepUp()</code></p>

<input type='range' id='number' step='10'/> 
<label id='value'>50</label>
```

```js
const numberEl = document.getElementById('number')
const valueEl = document.getElementById('value')

// Same issue is present when listening to 'change'
numberEl.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  valueEl.innerText = event.target.value
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.code === 'KeyJ'){
    numberEl.stepDown()
  }
  if (event.code === 'KeyK'){
    numberEl.stepUp()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to trigger the change event in the key down event manually since `onchange` only fires when the element loses focus

```
  ...

  if (event.code === 'KeyJ'){
    numberEl.stepDown()
  }
  if (event.code === 'KeyK'){
    numberEl.stepUp()
  }
  
  const ev = new Event('change');
  numberEl.dispatchEvent(ev);
...
```

Comment: Interesting, I would've assumed the `step` functions would've done this automatically but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: ya, it seems from the html spec that they never specify if the change event should be called so they left it up to the browser implementors. It seems that chrome doesnt trigger the event, I haven't tried firefox but i'm assuming it will do the same thing.